# Opencart VQMod conflicts with OCMod

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, vqmod

Error in vqmodManager: VQMod does not appear to be properly generating vqcache files!

```
Cache files are not generated in vqcache folder. -> vqMod not working
```

I´m using OC 2.0.1.1 and vqmod opencart-2-0-1-0-vqmod-2-5-1-3

What I have done to fix this:
- Permissions are 755 and I tried 777 too.

- Permissions of admin/index.php are 755 and tried 777 too.
- Permissions ofindex.php are 755 and tried 777 too.
- Permissions of vqmod and vqmod/vqcache folder 755 and tried 777 too.
- Complete reinstall of vqmod
- Deleted vqcache files
- Deleted mods.cache
- Deleted system/cache
- No logs file

It has worked after I installed opencart. But now I installed a NON vqmod extension and it stopped working.

**UPDATE**
I think it´s a problem between ocMod and vqMod. If I click the button "clear cache" in ocMod, the vqMod extensions are working, but not the ocMods. If click the button "refresh" in oCMod, the ocMod extensions are working but the vqMods doesn´t...

After clicking button "clear cache" there is no error. When I´m clicking directly after clearing cash the "refresh" button, this error shows up:

```
    Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /homepages/6/d421894284/htdocs/opencart/upload/admin/controller/extension/modification.php on line 160
Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /homepages/6/d421894284/htdocs/opencart/upload/admin/controller/extension/modification.php on line 160
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/6/d421894284/htdocs/opencart/upload/admin/index.php:80) in /homepages/6/d421894284/htdocs/opencart/upload/system/library/response.php on line 12
```

Comment: And yeah I know this is asked before. But without satisfying answer.

Comment: Did the non-vqmod extension overwrite any files?

Comment: no... thats the strange thing. It was Total Import Pro by Hostjars: http://opencart.hostjars.com/total-import-pro

Comment: What are the permissions of the vqmod/vqcache directory?

Comment: updated question. I have found out, that it is a problem with "refreshing" or "clear" the modification cache...

Comment: Gonna start a bounty on this

Comment: Please check these two links:- http://sv2109.com/en/article/how-fix-vqmod-errors-and-conflicts. And  http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=190&t=142352. I hope these two link may help you to resolve your problem. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a buggy extension you have installed... Looking at the file where the error occurred, there is no "strpos()" on line 160 (or anywhere near that line). It looks like you're not running the original OCMod modification.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like vQModManager is causing the problem.

Install [vQModerator](http://vqmoderator.com) instead.
It plays nice with both OCMods and vQMods.

Answer (score 0):

I was having very similar issues and conflicts with ocmod & vqmod until I discovered that some custom themes (particularly journal) unneccessarily replace 2 core files which can cause this to happen. It drove me absolutely nuts and took ages to find a solution which I eventually got from an opencart legend & friend. I'm not sure if you do have a custom theme or not but if you do (or anyone else stumbling across this does), then check the:

```
admin/controller/extension
```

folder and see if there are any backed up versions of install.php or modification.php.

If there are, restore the originals and this problem should go away. The newer files are not needed and both myself and friend have not had any complaints or errors from reverting back to the originals.

Hope this helps someone!